# How to make React Material-UI Accordion fill entire height?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I have 2 Material-ui Accordions which I want to expand to their full height in the following way:

- Both of them collapsed.
- One collapsed (take the maximum height possible)
- Both expanded (each take 50% of the full height)

Can I achieve this with the following code simply with CSS? (thought it should be possible with `flex-grow` and `flex-direction:column` but I can't get it to work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-tesla-uchsb?file=/accordionFullHeight

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    background: 'green',
    height: '90vh'
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
  },
}));

export default function SimpleAccordion() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Accordion 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
            sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel2a-content"
          id="panel2a-header"
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>Accordion 2</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
            sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved it using a controlled Accordion that uses `flex-grow:1` only when its expanded:

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-tesla-uchsb?file=/src/MyAccordion.js

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Accordion from "@material-ui/core/Accordion";
import AccordionDetails from "@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails";
import AccordionSummary from "@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    background: "red",
    color: "blue"
  },
  rootExpanded: {
    background: "blue",
    flexGrow: 1
  }
}));

export default function MyAccordion(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { name } = props;
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const rootClass = expanded ? classes.rootExpanded : classes.root;

  const handleChange = (panel) => (event, isExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

  return (
    <Accordion
      className={rootClass}
      expanded={expanded === name}
      onChange={handleChange(name)}
    >
      <AccordionSummary
        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
        id={`${name}-header`}
      >
        <Typography className={classes.heading}>General settings</Typography>
        <Typography className={classes.secondaryHeading}>
          I am an accordion
        </Typography>
      </AccordionSummary>
      <AccordionDetails>
        <Typography>
          Nulla facilisi. Phasellus sollicitudin nulla et quam mattis feugiat.
          Aliquam eget maximus est, id dignissim quam.
        </Typography>
      </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
  );
}
```